# Can't apply scale_x_log10() to my own geom: it appears on plot incorrectly

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

I'm trying to understand how `ggproto` works to write my own geoms.

I wrote **geom_myerrorbarh** (analogous to [geom_errorbarh](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_errorbarh.html), but only with `x`,`y`, `xwidth` arguments). The figure below shows that everything works correctly at a linear scale. However, if you use the log10 scale, it is different from **geom_errorbarh**.

I noticed that when using **scale_x_log10()**, `x=log10(x)` is converted first, and then `xmin=x-xwidth; xmax=x+xwidth` (see setup_data argument). But it should be `xmin=log10(x-width); xmax=log10(x+xwidth)`.

How to solve this problem?

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
theme_set(theme_minimal())
GeomMyerrorbarh <- ggproto("GeomMyerrorbarh", Geom,
                         required_aes = c("x", "y", "xwidth"),
                         draw_key = draw_key_path,
                         setup_data = function(data, params){
                           transform(data, xmin = x - xwidth, xmax = x + xwidth)
                         },
                         draw_group = function(data, panel_scales, coord) {
                           ## Transform the data first
                           coords <- coord$transform(data, panel_scales)

                           ## Construct a grid grob
                           grid::segmentsGrob(
                             x0 = coords$xmin,
                             x1 = coords$xmax,
                             y0 = coords$y,
                             y1 = coords$y,
                             gp = gpar(lwd = coords$size, 
                                       col = coords$colour,
                                       alpha = coords$alpha))
                           
                         })

geom_myerrorbarh <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity",
                           position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, 
                           show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  
  ggplot2::layer(
    geom = GeomMyerrorbarh, mapping = mapping,  
    data = data, stat = stat, position = position, 
    show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  )
}

df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2), 
                 y = c(1, 2),
                 xerr = c(0.1, 0.2))

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = x - xerr, xmax = x + xerr), 
                 height=0, size=4, alpha=0.2, color='red') +
  geom_myerrorbarh(aes(xwidth = xerr)) + 
  labs(subtitle = 'Linear scale x')

p2 <- p1 + 
  scale_x_log10() + 
  labs(subtitle = 'Log10 scale x')

# Plot:
# Red transparent region - geom_errorbarh
# Black line - geom_myerrorbarh
p1 | p2
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 1):

Oh... this is a fun one to dissect.

To pinpoint when various changes take place, I ran `debugonce(ggplot_build)`, to see what goes on underneath the hood when a ggplot object is being printed, and the following steps show up when I print `p2`:

```
# earlier steps omitted

  data <- by_layer(function(l, d) l$layer_data(plot$data), 
    layers, data, "computing layer data")
  data <- by_layer(function(l, d) l$setup_layer(d, plot), 
    layers, data, "setting up layer")
  layout <- create_layout(plot$facet, plot$coordinates)
  data <- layout$setup(data, plot$data, plot$plot_env)
  data <- by_layer(function(l, d) l$compute_aesthetics(d, 
    plot), layers, data, "computing aesthetics")
  data <- lapply(data, scales_transform_df, scales = scales)

# later steps omitted
```

Let's run through the steps sequentially, & print out our data object in console to see what has happened to it after every step

**Step 1**: Computing layer data

```
[[1]]
  x y xerr
1 1 1  0.1
2 2 2  0.2

[[2]]
  x y xerr
1 1 1  0.1
2 2 2  0.2

[[3]]
  x y xerr
1 1 1  0.1
2 2 2  0.2
```

Nothing interesting to see here. The inputted data frame `df` has simply been replicated for each layer of the ggplot object.

**Step 2**: Setting up layer

```
# no change from above
```

Moving on.

**Step 3**: Creating layout & running `layout$setup` on data

```
[[1]]
  x y xerr PANEL
1 1 1  0.1     1
2 2 2  0.2     1

[[2]]
  x y xerr PANEL
1 1 1  0.1     1
2 2 2  0.2     1

[[3]]
  x y xerr PANEL
1 1 1  0.1     1
2 2 2  0.2     1
```

Panel column added. Irrelevant for our investigation since we aren't messing around with facets (i.e. PANEL = 1 throughout).

**Step 4**: Computing aesthetics

```
[[1]]
  x y PANEL group
1 1 1     1    -1
2 2 2     1    -1

[[2]]
  xmin xmax x y PANEL group
1  0.9  1.1 1 1     1    -1
2  1.8  2.2 2 2     1    -1

[[3]]
  xwidth x y PANEL group
1    0.1 1 1     1    -1
2    0.2 2 2     1    -1
```

Finally, the different data layers are starting to distinguish themselves from one another. For each layer, new columns are added based on its specific aesthetic mappings, and unused columns from the original dataset are stripped away. A group column has also been added at the back.

**Step 5**: Scales transformation

```
[[1]]
        x y PANEL group
1 0.00000 1     1    -1
2 0.30103 2     1    -1

[[2]]
        x        xmin       xmax y PANEL group
1 0.00000 -0.04575749 0.04139269 1     1    -1
2 0.30103  0.25527251 0.34242268 2     1    -1

[[3]]
        x xwidth y PANEL group
1 0.00000    0.1 1     1    -1
2 0.30103    0.2 2     1    -1
```

Here, the 2nd and 3rd data layers have become truly different from one another. In layer 2, the scales transformation `log10(.)` has been applied directly to `x`, `xmin` and `xmax`, while layer 3 only received the same transformation for `x`.

There are two issues here. I have a workaround for one issue, but it's useless because the second issue remains.

**Issue 1**: No transformation on `xwidth`.

If we dig into `scales_transform_df` to see how it works, we'll find an exhaustive list of column names that `scale_x_log10` will consider, when performing transformations. This can be assessed at the surface debugging level with `scales$scales[[1]]$aesthetics`, and corresponds to `ggplot_global$x_aes`:

```
 [1] "x"          "xmin"       "xmax"       "xend"       "xintercept" "xmin_final"
 [7] "xmax_final" "xlower"     "xmiddle"    "xupper"     "x0"
```

Okay, we can rename `"xwidth"` to one of the above, no biggie. Call it `xmiddle`, for example, & we'll go from `xmin = log_10(x) - xwidth; xmax = log(x) + xwidth` (OP's original situation) to `xmin = log_10(x) - log_10(xwidth); xmax = log_10(x) + log_10(xwidth)`. That's closer, but still not good enough, which brings us to...

**Issue 2**: The data transformation defined in `GeomMyerrorbarh`'s `setup_data` function happens much, much later.

In my copy of the `ggplot_build.ggplot` function, the scales transformation happens in line 18, and the calculation for `xmin = x - width` / `xmax = x + width` defined in `setup_data` is called by `compute_geom_1()` in line 28. If we want the `log_10(.)` transformation applied to the calculated `xmin` / `xmax` values, these calculations have to happen *before* the scales transformation.

## Is it worth the trouble to address this within `ggplot_build`?

I'm leaning towards no, because I think it's not a Geom's core job to perform data transformations.

I'm not familiar with the thinking behind the function's design, but I imagine a change such as bringing up the geom's `setup_data` (or, equivalently, shoving down `scales_transform_df`) will be a non-trivial one, potentially breaking other things along the way.

This use case sounds like it can be more easily served with a wrapper function around one or more existing `geom_*()` functions that accept the final `xmin` / `xmax` values, and perform data transformations within the wrapper.

## Has it occurred for other Geoms?

Somewhat surprisingly (to me at least), yes.

This exact problem shows up in the ggplot2 package's own `geom_tile` function, as its underlying `GeomTile` performs the data transformation in `setup_data` too. Here's a simple illustration to trigger it, using my current version (ggplot2 3.4.0):

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(c(3, 6, 8, 10, 13), 2),
  y = rep(c(1, 2), each = 5),
  z = factor(rep(1:5, each = 2)),
  w = rep(diff(c(0, 4, 6, 8, 10, 14)), 2)
)

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(fill = z)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = x - w/2, xmax = x + w/2,
                ymin = y - 0.5, ymax = y + 0.5), 
            colour = "grey50", alpha = 0.5, linewidth = 1) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = x, y = y, width = w, height = 1),
            colour = "grey50", alpha = 0.5, linewidth = 1) +
  ggtitle("linear scales") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

p2 <- p1 + scale_x_log10() + ggtitle("transformed x scale")
p3 <- p1 + scale_y_log10() + ggtitle("transformed y scale")
p4 <- p1 + scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10() + ggtitle("transformed both scales")

library(patchwork)
(p1 | p2) / (p3 | p4)
```

The `geom_rect` layer accepts the aesthetic mappings `c(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)`, while `geom_tile` accepts `c(x, y, width, height)`. They look identical when default linear scales are used, but go out of sync once transformed scales are introduced in either direction. The `geom_tile` version even overlaps with itself!

[image: 4 plots patched together for comparison]

That said, transforming scales while drawing tiles (for a heatmap?) seems like a rather niche use case, and I haven't seen this issue brought up elsewhere before. Perhaps a cautionary note in the help files, warning against using scale transformations, would suffice, unless the community has more pressing arguments for its usefulness.